# Apple TV is not connected : Apple TV will continue when Living Room is connected

Tags: xcode, tvos, apple-tv

I am developing an Apple TV app with Xcode.
Every time I leave Apple TV untouched for a long period of time (an hour or so), it gets disconnected:
[image]

This is the error:

> Failed _shouldMakeReadyForDevelopment check even though device is not
> locked by passcode.
> allowsSecureServices: 1. isConnected: 0. Platform:
> DVTPlatform:0x7fd21e57e7a0:'com.apple.platform.appletvos':<DVTFilePath:0x7fd21e57f5a0:'/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/AppleTVOS.platform'>.
> DTDKDeviceIdentifierIsIDID: 0

So when I try to build, I get stuck in here:
[image]

This is making developing a tvOS app near impossible, since so much of my time is spent debugging why the Apple TV is not correctly paired/connected to my Mac.

---

**NOTE1:** I've tried unpairing&pairing again, restarting the Apple TV and the Mac, resetting the Apple TV and still no result.
**NOTE2:** I have the latest Xcode version installed.
**NOTE3:** Similar questions have been asked on stack overflow but none of them tackled the tvOS problem in particular. And I have also tried their proposed solutions.
**NOTE4:** Apple TV is connected to my Mac through WiFi.

Comment: The easiest way to solve this is to get a router switch and use lan connections instead of wifi. I know that is a pain, but I have been doing tvOS development for two years now and getting Xcode to connect and build correctly to it is almost impossible some times.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and found that leaving Xcode on the "is not connected" dialogue and turning the Apple TV off and on fixed it. (I have both my mac and AppleTV connected to the same switch via ethernet.)

I also have a factory-reset Apple TV with no PIN. It's possible there's some configuration that prevents this from working for you. Maybe a factory reset would fix it?

Edit: After developing with the Apple TV 4K UHD for a month, I have frequent issues like this, but not always the same. Usually I can't connect and need to re-pair (even though it's already paired). Sometimes pairing appears to succeed, but the device isn't usable. Sometimes even restarting my mac and tvos fail to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was happening to me that AppleTV was a version ahead of Xcode, so to solve the issue was just updating the Xcode.

Another solution can be remove the sync from Mac and AppleTV and add again

```
(AppleTV) -> Settings > Remotes and Devices > "Remote App and Devices" remove

(Xcode mac) -> Window menu > "Devices and Simulators" and also remove
```

Then just add again :)

Comment: still got same problem

Comment: @MetinAtalay reboot the apple tv and mac? ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I did but same (